# Error - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I am currently getting this error on one of my files:

```
  /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/generator/index.php on line 6
```

Line 6 would be resulting in:

```
  echo $results->GetBookCodesResult->BookCodes->BookInfo->ServiceCode;
```

My code:

```
  <?php
  $config['soap_url'] = "http://myservice.com?WSDL";
  if(isset($_REQUEST['codes'])) {
    $results = request_Data(explode("\n",$_REQUEST['codes']));
    echo $results->GetBookCodesResult->BookCodes->BookInfo->ServiceCode;
  }
  ....
```

What is the best method to have this fixed? Some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump()` `$result` to see if it contains what you think / hope it does.

Answer (score 2):

your "->BookCodes" sub-property is empty as you can see in your var_dump-output...

this property "BookInfo" just not exist.. maybe no books are found? ;)

Comment: Thank you TheHe - I have edited the code and how I get the following: Call to undefined method stdClass::GetBookCodesResult()

Comment: do a "var_dump($results)" and post us the output please

Comment: object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetBookCodesResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (5) { ["ResultCode"]=> int(0) ["IsSuccess"]=> bool(true) ["Message"]=> string(7) "Success" ["BookCodes"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (0) { } ["NotFoundISBN"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["string"]=> string(5) "45646" } }}

Comment: Thank you TheHe! I have seen now to generate the example with a valid input - the var_dump is as follows: object(stdClass)#2 (1) {  ["GetBookCodesResult"]=>  object(stdClass)#3 (5) {    ["ResultCode"]=>    int(0)    ["IsSuccess"]=>    bool(true)    ["Message"]=>    string(7) "Success"    ["BookCodes"]=>    object(stdClass)#4 (1) {      ["BookInfo"]=>      object(stdClass)#5 (2) {        ["OokbeeCode"]=>        string(36) "768e0ec3-d1ed-4ea3-92d4-d6e38126ab2e"        ["ISBN"]=>        string(18) "BMB-011-024-000021"      }    }    ["NotFoundISBN"]=>    object(stdClass)#6 (0) {    }  }}

Comment: It is strange though because the script is working fine on one hosting provider but results in the above mentioned error on the current host.

Comment: am i wrong or there is "ServiceCode" missing now? ;)
in the var_dump output you can follow the property-chain to see what's wrong here!

Comment: check if a property exists before attempting to access it